# Java - Make character after space uppercase?

Tags: java

I'm trying to have the letter after every space turn uppercase. Can someone tell me what's wrong with the following method? Given `phrase` "this is a test" it returns "ThIs Is A TesT" instead of "this Is A Test"

```java
public String toTitleCase(String phrase) {
    for (int i=0; i<phrase.length(); i++) {
        if(phrase.substring(i,i+1).equals(" ")) {
            phrase = phrase.replace(phrase.substring(i+1,i+2),phrase.substring(i+1,i+2).toUpperCase());
        }
    }
    return phrase;
}
```

Comment: there are many ways to do this https://howtodoinjava.com/java/string/convert-string-to-titlecase/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's replacing all `t`, try below code.

It will help you.

```
 String phrase="this is a test";
            for (int i=0; i<phrase.length(); i++) {
                if(phrase.substring(i,i+1).equals(" ")) {
                    System.out.println(phrase.substring(i+1,i+2));
                    phrase = phrase.replace(phrase.substring(i,i+2),phrase.substring(i,i+2).toUpperCase());
                }
            }
System.out.println(phrase);
```

Answer (score 2):

The problem in your code is that [`String.replace`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/14/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/String.html#replace(java.lang.CharSequence,java.lang.CharSequence)) replaces each target character present in the `String`, and not only the one you want.

You could work directly on an array of chars instead of on the `String`:

```
public static String toTitleCase(String phrase) {

    // convert the string to an array 
    char[] phraseChars = phrase.toCharArray();

    for (int i = 0; i < phraseChars.length - 1; i++) {
        if(phraseChars[i] == ' ') {
            phraseChars[i+1] = Character.toUpperCase(phraseChars[i+1]);
        }
    }

    // convert the array to string
    return String.valueOf(phraseChars);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Use streams (or split) to split your string into parts, don't do it manually using substring.

Try below code

```
        String test = "this is a test";

        UnaryOperator<String> capitalize = str ->
                str.substring(0,1).toUpperCase() + str.substring(1).toLowerCase();

        String result =
                Stream.of(
                        test.split(" ")
                ).map(capitalize)
                .collect(
                        Collectors.joining(" ")
                );

        System.out.println(result);
```

Output: `This Is A Test`

Answer (score 1):

When you replace a substring it will replace the each occurrence of that substring - which is not necessarily the one you are trying to replace.  This is why it is replacing letters inside words.

Switching to a StringBuilder here to poke individual characters.  Note that we don't traverse the entire String because there is no next-character to capitalize at the last character.

```
public String toTitleCase(String phrase) {
  StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder(phrase);
  for (int index = 0 ; index < phrase.length - 1 ; ++index) {
    if (sb.charAt(index) == ' ') {
      sb.setCharAt(index + 1, Character.toUppercase(sb.charAt(index + 1)));
    }
  }
  return sb.toString();
}
```

Comment: This is basically the same answer as given by @Loris Securo - the only difference is I'm using a StringBuilder rather than a char[].

Answer (score 1):

If a letter is first in any word, it will be replaced everywhere. In your case, all *t,i and a* will be uppercase.
Taking example for **is**. It is find a space before. Than in if body, what actually happen:

```
phrase = phrase.replace("i","I");
```

And all i are replaced with I.
String class cannot replace at a specific position.

You have to options:

- using StringBuilder which can replace at a specific position.

```
String toTitleCase(String phrase) {
        StringBuilder sb= new StringBuilder(phrase);
        for (int i=0; i<phrase.length(); i++) {
            if(i==0 || phrase.charAt(i-1)==' ') {
                sb.replace(i,i+1,phrase.substring(i,i+1).toUpperCase());
            }
        }
        return sb.toString();
    }
```

- or with stream, which is the method I prefer because is one-line. This way you don't preserve white-spaces( multiple consecutive white-spaces will be replaced with only one space), but usually you want this.

```
Arrays.asList(phrase.split("\\s+")).stream().map(x->x.substring(0,1).toUpperCase()+x.substring(1)).collect(Collectors.joining(" "));
```